# Use installed file which name contain hyphen via composer

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I'd like to use installed file via composer. However, its name has hyphens. So, I’m troubled. How do I use in case of the situation?

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",

    "j7mbo/twitter-api-php": "dev-master"
},
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Although you got an answer, your question is still lacking almost all needed information. Please answer these questions: 1. What did you do? 2. What was the result? 3. What did you expect as the result instead? 4. How does the result you got differ from your expectation?

Comment: 1. First, input "j7mbo/twitter-api-php": "dev-master" to composer.json 2. execute composer update 3. checked target files were imported to vendor folder.  Then, I don't understand what I should after 3. Although I try the statement, "use j7mbo\twitterapiphp\TwitterAPIExchange;" it occured error. The error message was that 'Attempted to call an undefined method named "outputTwitterJson" of class "AppBundle\Controller\JsonController".
Did you mean to call "getTwitterJson"?' 3. expected result is display JSON 4. Contrary to only php file, I couldn't do the command like require_once on Symfony.

Comment: Is there any hyphen in the file name? I don't see any one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since composer packages aren't case-sensitive, hyphens (or dash) are used as an alternative to CamelCace notation:

> Note that package names are case-insensitive, but it's encouraged to
>   use a dash (-) as separator instead of CamelCased names.

Source: https://packagist.org/about

Class names can't contain hyphens, but are case-sensitive. You can use it's CamelCase class name. In your case, `TwitterAPIExchange.php` is [autoloaded](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/composer.json), so you can use:

```
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
```